# Expanding UITextView in UITableViewCell leaves gap at bottom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have successfully implemented a `UITextView` within a `UITableViewCell`. I have put the `UITextField` into the cell and specified constraints, so that the text view is always 10 points from the top and bottom of the cell (thus, when the cell increases in size so will the text view):

[image]

I have also included the following code (which seems to be the recommended iOS 7 way) to remove all content insets and padding from the text view:

```
expandingTextViewCell.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
expandingTextViewCell.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

All cell heights are stored in an array, which `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` queries.
I have implemented the relevant code in the `-textViewDidChange:` method to inspect the new text which has been typed into the text view, recalculate the heights, update the array, and then call `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` to animate the change in cell height. This all works, and the text view also resizes (due to the defined constraints):

[image]

However, there's one issue I have been unable to solve. When sufficient text is typed to result in the cell (and text view) expanding, the text view appears to scroll upwards - this cuts off the first line of text, and also creates a gap at the bottom of the text view:

[image]

You can see the issue in the above screen shot. However, if I manually scroll the text view back to it's proper position then everything displays fine, and I can not scroll the text view down to get the gap again, that gap has now disappeared:

[image]

I would appreciate any assistance to get rid of that gap which appears when the cell / text view expands. From the user's perspective, I just want the text view to grow / expand downwards with the previously typed text remaining in its original place.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but the same problem still exists in iOS 10.

This answer to the similar question was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480403/7604418

You can add a category to UITextView to disable content offset animation, and that fixes the extra bottom offset:

```
@implementation UITextView (Scroll)
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
}
@end
```