# UITextView content offset changes after setting frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm building a view that's very similar to the messages app - I have a subview at the bottom of the page with a `UITextView` in it and as the user types and reaches the end of the line the text view as well as the view containing it should expand upward.

The way I have it working is that in the `textViewDidChange:` method I call my layout function, and that does

```
CGFloat textViewWidth = 200;
CGFloat textViewHeight = [self.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, 2000)].height;
[self resizeParentWithTextViewSize:CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, textViewHeight)];

// And then the resize parent method eventually calls
textView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, textViewWidth, textViewHeight);
```

The problem is that when typing at the end of line and the view expands, I end up with an arbitrary `contentOffset.y` of something like 10.5 on the text view so the text is all shifted up to the top of the view. Weirdly, it's alternating on every other line, so expanding the first time leaves the y content offset shifted up, then at the next line it's close to zero, then back to 10.5 on the next line, etc.  (not sure if that's helpful or just a strange artifact of my values). I can set it back to zero afterwards but it looks terrible because there's a brief flash where the text has the offset value and then it gets shifted back to the middle.

I've read that it's usually better to use content insets for scroll views rather than changing the frame, but I don't get how to do that because I do need to change the frame size as well.

How can I resize the `UITextView` without this happening? I think I can get by with setting the text view not to be scrollable and that fixes the issue, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi Danny, were you able to resolve this problem? I am facing the same issue for a messenger like UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `textView.scrollable = NO` lets me resize the text view without any strange offsets, that's the only way I've been able to figure out. And I guess it's not too much of a limitation for common scenarios, if you want the text view to be scrollable you probably don't need to resize it on the fly since the user can scroll around as the content changes.

Comment: Thanks Danny. While making textview.scrollable = NO will let me change the frame without any problem, it will not behave similar to the messenger like textview. If we consider text input area of Whatsapp, it grows as user types until it reaches a certain number of lines. After that, it enables scrolling. I have not tried using Autolayout yet, I was trying it the old way of changing frames.

Comment: @Siddhesh ahh, well to have the input area grow you have to manually resize it. What I've done is in the text view delegate `textViewDidChange:` method, call `layoutSubviews` on the view that contains the textview (more specifically, on the highest level parent view that will need to change its size to allow the text view to grow/shrink, often the view controller's root view).  Then in the appropriate layout subviews method, call `[textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)]` where width is the width the textview will need, and then in setFrame set the size of the text view to that

Comment: For your case, you'll want to do something like use your max height requirement instead of CGFLOAT_MAX, and then if the resulting size hits that max set scrollable = YES *instead of* changing the size of the text view.     Also worth noting, it's still manual here if you are using auto-layout. As far as I can tell, with autolayout you have to manually set a height constraint on the textView and then in `updateConstraints` manually set that height constraint's constant to be equal to the sizeThatFits: height.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that UITextView's scroll animation and your frame setting action were happened at the same time.
UITextView internally scrolls the texts you currently typing to visible when typed one more character at the end of the line or typed the new line character. But the scroll animation does not need because you are expanding the textview. Unfortunately we can't control textview's internal scroll action so the text scrolls to the top of the expanded textview weirdly. And that weird scroll makes unnecessary bottom padding too.

You can avoid this weird action very simply with overriding UITextView's setContentOffset:animated: like this.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
    super.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
}
```

This code avoids the auto sizing UITextView's unnecessary scroll animations and you can expand the size of the text view freely.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I confronted the same issue: changing the `UITextView`'s frame to fit its content had a side effect on the scroll position being wrong. The `UITextView` scrolled even when the `contentSize` was fitting the `bounds`.

I ended up with setting `scrollEnabled` to `true` and with rolling the content offset back if the `UITextView` is not actually scrollable

```
override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
    didSet {
        if iOS8 {
            // here the contentOffset may become non zero whereas it shouldn't be
            if !isContentScrollable && contentOffset.y > 0 {
                contentOffset.y = 0
            }
        }
    }
}    

var isContentScrollable: Bool {
    let result = ceil(contentSize.height) > ceil(height)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I faced the same issue and found that actually this happens only when UITextView has any Autolayout constraints. If you will try to use UITextView without applying any Constraint then this will not happen and will work fine. but, as you apply Auto layout constraints it automatically scrolls to bottom. To deal with this I just add method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```